# Editing php5.conf

Tags: apache2, php

I am trying to edit /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf but when I try to do vi /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf it just comes up as

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            php_admin_value engine Off
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
Type  :quit<Enter>  to exit Vim
```

and I can not edit it, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try gedit instead of vi. Vi is really confusing if you haven't used old command-line text editors like that before, and people should really stop using it in tutorials and expecting newbies to understand it.

Gedit is a GUI editor, almost like Notepad with syntax highlighting. You should have no problem with it.